# Why is only "Generic Simulator" showing and the menu item "iOS and Mac" grayed out in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, msbuild, visual-studio-mac

I am using Visual Studio for Mac and I am wondering why is the menu item `"iOS and Mac"` disabled under main menu `Tools`.

And also my iPhone Simulator is not showing up to deploy an iOS app in the simulator.

I've set my Apple SDK path in Visual Studio's preferences as follow. `/Applications/Xcode.app/`

My macOS and Visual Studio versions are :

```
macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac 8.10.8 (build 0)
Xamarin.iOS 12.6.0.25
Xcode 10.1
```

[image]

Comment: those are headers, not menu items.  The items under "iOS" apply to iOS, the items under "Android" apply to Android

Comment: i see... i was confused... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the way to fix showing generic simulator only. I simply `unload the Xamarin.iOS project` in the solution and `reload it` and `set it as startup project`. It is just simple as that. I got the right way from this answer by someone else. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61899711/5841944

Comment: See another comment from that linked answer about Xamarin and XCode compatibility. The compatible version of Visual Studio for Mac was not ready yet at the time of the XCode 14 release, so also there only the Generic Simulator was available.